# Get OS Type if 32bit or 64bit in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight 5 application and needs to check the client side operating system type if it's 32bit or 64bit OS.

**Environment Class** dosen't help.

I used the code

**//C# Code**

**var bitSize = IntPtr.Size * 8; // returns 32**

But, it return 32 while the OS is Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64 bit base on the system property.
START>Computer>System Properties>

What is wrong with my code.

Comment: Its its running on a web page can you send the user agent to silverlight?

Comment: It's running in Web page. We set the application to not support the out-of-browser functionality. For query "can you send the user agent to silverlight?" - can you please elaborate more. I didn't userstood what you mean.

Comment: Take a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403727/how-to-detect-the-os-from-a-silverlight-application

A user agent contains loads of details, so you could print it on the page from ASP or PHP then silverlight can pick it up.

An example agent is this: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36. I believe if it says WOW64 then its windows 64bt

http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/